# C Error - macro "max" requires 2 arguments, but only 1 given

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

While trying to compile the code below:

```
template <class T>
struct scalar_log_minimum {
    public:
        typedef T value_type;
        typedef T result_type;
        static
            result_type initial_value(){
                return std::log(std::numeric_limits<result_type>::max());
        }
        static
            void update(result_type& t, const value_type& x){
                if ( (x>0) && (std::log(x)<t) ) t = std::log(x);
        }
    };
```

I got the following error :

`functional_ext.hpp:55:59: macro "max" requires 2 arguments, but only 1 given`

Here "max" is not a macro, right? Then what is this error? BTW, I am using Visual Studio 2005.

Also what does 55:59 mean - 55 is the line number 59?

Comment: 59 is the column number?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I find the many #defines that you encounter once you included windows.h very disturbing (not only max and min, but I also had problems with other generic words like Rectangle if I'm not mistaken). Therefore, I have developed the habit to include windows.h only when absolutely necessary, and never in header files. This reduces the pain to a small number of C++ files that are platform-specific.

Unfortunately some boost libraries (I believe thread and asio) do include windows.h in their headers, and I still run into this kind of silly problems from time to time.

My solution for the remainder of the situations where this causes problems is to #undef the problematic symbols after the inclusion of the header files.

Answer (score 7):

You're including a header file somewhere that `#define`s `max` as a macro.  The best solution would be to figure out where it's being defined, and inhibit it from being defined if possible.  Alternatively, you could just `#undef` it:

```
#include <evil_header_which_defines_max.h>
#undef max
```

Comment: I had similar problems with MSVC, I think it's in their library headers.

Comment: windef.h (usually included via windows.h) contains such an offending define and frequently causes headaches for STL users.

Answer (score 3):

As others have noted, including `windows.h` is probably your problem.  Microsoft provides a means to "turn off" parts of `windows.h` with preprocessor symbols.  You can define these symbols as part of your build or directly in code.

Using preprocessor symbols to conditionally skip sections of `windows.h` may or may not be considered elegant but in the general case it is an easier, more general and more scalable solution than `#undef`.

Here's how to skip defining `min` or `max` as macros:

```
#define NOMINMAX
#include <windows.h>
```

Note that many include files will, at some point, include `windows.h`.  In such cases setting up your defines at a more global level may be more convenient.

If you search through `windows.h`, you can find a bunch of other preprocessor symbols (e.g., `NOOPENFILE`, `NOKANJI`, `NOKERNEL` and many others) that can often be useful.

Answer (score 2):

It's a macro called `max` that gets into the way as Adam explained. Another solution (more a "hotfix") may be to put parentheses around the function, to prevent it from being seen as a macro invocation:

```
return std::log((std::numeric_limits<result_type>::max)());
```